# Calling a function in JavaScript defined under a separate script from a 2nd script

Tags: javascript

**Question:-**

How can I call a function defined under a different script in the same javascript file from another function in a different script ?

**Explanation:-**

So I have 2 scripts in the same javascript file (default.aspx)

I have one script that does a jquery...

```
$.Ajax { .... OnScucess: Onsuccess () function}

Onsuccess() { call another function called date_label() }
```

This `date_label()` function is defined in a separate script... where there is a function called

```
timeLine(){ within it is the function date_label() {....} }
```

Now when I try to call date_label in my `Onsuccess()` function I get an obvious error message - undefined. But I believe there must be someway to make it work. Any ideas?

I was looking at this:-

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/11206/call-a-function-in-a-different-script-using-javasc.html

but I dont have names for my script tags...

Comment: It's all about scope and order.

Comment: What's the scope for `date_label()`?

Comment: I was just reading about scope:_

http://hangar.runway7.net/javascript/guide

Answer (score 1):

There's a few ways to fix this, and all of them involve controlling the scope of `date_label()`.  The easiest fix (which will get me yelled at shortly) is to make `date_label()` global.  In the file, you'd simply have:

```
function date_label()
{
   // Implementation
}
```

Make sure this function is not *nested* within another scope, such as another function.  As long as this script file has been loaded before `date_label` is called, you'll be fine.  What physical `.js` file the functions are located in is completely irrelevant.

However, usually you don't want to *pollute* the global scope.  For this reason, you might want to put this function within a namespace, which is usually just an object literal:

```
var MyUtils =
{
   date_label: function ()
   {
      // Implementation
   }
};
```

You would then be able to call this function anywhere like so:

```
MyUtils.date_label();
```

It's often common practice to define a namespace for your app or your library, as not to conflict with other code that might be on the page as well.

Comment: so to implement your second method... where do i 'put' the namespace? do I have to define a 'special tag'

Comment: You can put the namespace anywhere.  Here's a [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/zyLVb/).

Comment: but date_label() has canvas functionalities in it, and it must be defined within the canvas tag...with the appropriate canvas definitions.. for example:- // defining the canvas element var can = document.getElementById("myCanvas"), ctx = can.getContext("2d"),

Comment: Here is a more indepth explanation of what I m trying to achieve:-

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14901941/drawing-a-timeline-on-a-canvas-after-an-ajax-request

Comment: Hmm, yea the function appears to be global so it should be accessible anywhere.  There must be something else going on.  I don't think I have enough information to tell you exactly what's wrong, I'd have to see it in my own browser to debug.

Comment: So if you notice, currently the labeling on the x-axis (dates) is manually set, in the date() function within my canvas tag. However my final goal is to update that date labeling dynamically with my jquery return values.. OPfromDate is where the date starts on the timeline and OPthruDate is where the timeline ends. Let me know if that makes sense.